# Pushing value to empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to push the value I get from the onlick to a empty array and I cant seem to get it right.

```
var result = [];

$('#submitButton').click(function(){

var textField = $('#textField').val();

$('#result').append(textField, '<br/>'); 

$('#textField').val('');
 result($(this).val());
```

});

Comment: `result.push($(this).val())`

Comment: Where in code are you pushing to array?

Comment: @SandeepNayak they're not

Comment: @Weedoze is there a dupe target for this? Or should we just leave it be?

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is a dupe

Answer (score 0):

Use this to push values in array

```
result.push($(this).val())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];

$('#submitButton').click(function(){

var textField = $('#textField').val();

$('#result').append(textField, '<br/>'); 

$('#textField').val('');
 result.push($(this).val()); /* You have to use push method */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `this` refers to button(`#submitButton`), not to element of which you want to access value.

Use `Array.prototype.push` to push value in `array`

```js
var result = [];
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
  var textField = $('#textField').val();
  $('#result').append(textField, '<br/>');
  $('#textField').val('');
  result.push(textField);
});
```

Comment: thank you its annoying when its something so small I overlook